# End to End Encryption Using Apache Pulsar Per Tenant/Topic

Tags: encryption, multi-tenant, apache-pulsar

I'm trying to incorporate end to end encryption using Apache Pulsar.  So far the examples I've seen look similar to http://pulsar.apache.org/docs/en/security-encryption/

I saw that the encryption key (public / private key) is fetched every 4 hours in the key rotation section.  It seems to indicate that you can only have a single key to encrypt the messages you send.

I’d like to be able to use different encryption keys for different topics/tenants. Does pulsar support different encryption keys for different topics?

Basically my client will pull a different key depending on which tenant the data belongs to and encrypt any messages pertaining to that specific key using pulsar's end to end encryption.

How would this look?

Is it as simple as creating a new producer any time I want to use a different key for encryption?

```
Producer producer = pulsarClient.newProducer()
                .topic("persistent://my-tenant/my-ns/my-topic")
                .addEncryptionKey("myTenant1Key")
                .cryptoKeyReader(new RawFileKeyReader("tenant1_pubkey.pem", "tenant1_privkey.pem"))
                .create();
```

So far I've used the pulsar client to send encrypted messages using a local private/public key pair.  Can I just switch out the key pair and instantiate a new producer anytime I want a message to be encrypted differently?  I've tried asking around and can't find the right answer.

Answer (score 0):

Absolutely, you are creating separate producers for different topic and can use different keys for each producer.